# How do I open a reference in another frame

Tags: html, css

I have a frame set with 2 frames.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<frameset cols="10%,*">
   <frame src="Meniu.html">
   <frame src="Secundar.html">
</frameset>
</html>
```

The output is this:
[Frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85NLz.png)

When I click on one of the references from the left frame, it opens in the same small frame, but how do I make to open the reference in the right frame, the bigger frame?

Comment: Wow - this is the first time I've seen `<frameset>` used _unironically_ in at least 17 years. How did you stumble upon this piece of ancient internet history?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: `<frameset>` and `<frame>` are **obsolete** and do not work well in web-browsers at all. I can only conclude you're learning how to write HTML from a book published before 1997 - or you're a cruel sadist.

---

With that out of the way: Use the `target=""` attribute on your `<a>` and `<form>` elements to specify the `<frame>` by its `name=""` attribute.